# Question about an inequality in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is the following inequality about probability true?$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(T\geq i)\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}cP(T\geq ci)$$
Here $c>1$, an integer. $T$ is just a random variable taking non-negative integer values.

I have been thinking about this for over 3 hours. My progress so far is only that$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(T\geq i) \leq c\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(T\geq i)$$ since $c>1$, but then in fact $P(T\geq i)\geq P(T\geq ci)$ since $T\geq ci$ implies $T\geq i$, so it seems I cannot achieve the $\leq$ conclusion.

This is one step in a proof of the expected value of Gambler's Ruin game's stopping time being finite. But I was stuck here trying to understand that. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i\ge 1} \mathsf{P}(T\ge i)\le \int_0^{\infty} \mathsf{P}(T\ge t)\,dt=c\int_0^{\infty} \mathsf{P}(T\ge ct)\,dt\le c\sum_{i\ge 0}\mathsf{P}(T\ge ci).
$$

Comment: Hi dko, thanks a lot, could you justify the validity of using integral instead of sum? $T$ here is a discrete random variable. Could you also explain the two inequalities you wrote between sums and integrals?

Comment: @xf16 $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{T \geq i\} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i \mathbb{P}\{T \geq i\} dt  \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i \mathbb{P}\{T \geq t\} dt = \int_{0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{T \geq t\} dt$$ where the inequality comes from the fact  that $\mathbb{P}\{T \geq u\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{T \geq t\}$ for $u \geq t$.

Comment: @xf16 It may be helpful to draw the cdf of some discrete r.v. (say, taking 2-3 values) and verify those inequities.

Comment: @ClementC. Hi Clement, I understand your derivation for the left inequality, but why is the right inequality also true? By intuition, should it be $\geq$ instead of $\leq$? The values of $t$ in the integral takes more values than $i$ in the summation.

Comment: For fixed $i$, $\int_{i}^{i+1}\mathsf{P}(T\ge ct)\,dt\le \mathsf{P}(T\ge ci)$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks dko, I got it now!